# I am trying to find a way to prevent truncation of resume token

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-kafka-connector, debezium-connect

I am trying to find a way to prevent truncation of resume tokenwhen error is thrown by mongodb server for 16 mb size limit. I am reading resume token to make sure documents over 16 mb is read properly but the script is not able to read the resume token as it is truncated and cant be found in db. What is way out?

can this be logging correction or debezium mongo connector or java driver? Please help here. Token string is truncated as highlighted

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.RetriableException: An exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will be restarted.
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler.setProducerThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:49)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.streamChangesForReplicaSet(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:122)
    at 
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:109)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Error while attempting to read from change stream on 'gng1/mongo-lentra-los-cd-txn-node-01.aws.serviceurl.internal:10085,mongo-lentra-los-cd-txn-node-02.aws.serviceurl.internal:10085,mongo-lentra-los-cd-txn-node-03.aws.serviceurl.internal:10085'
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.lambda$establishConnection$3(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:170)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.ConnectionContext$MongoPreferredNode.execute(ConnectionContext.java:381)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.streamChangesForReplicaSet(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:115)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 10334 (BSONObjectTooLarge): 'BSONObj size: 19821386 (0x12E734A) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: _id: { _data: "**826582F765000000EE2B022C01E5A1004C94025F689C1431EBF7CA2720270CD87463C5F6964003C3330323343443030313535303368425835427270325548413957483667666A6C50...**" }' on server mongo-lentra-los-cd-txn-node-03.aws.serviceurl.internal:10085. The full response is {"operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1703095214, "i": 20}}, "ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "BSONObj size: 19821386 (0x12E734A) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: _id: { _data: \"**826582F765000000EE2B022C0100296E5A1004C94025F689C1431EBF7CA2720270CD87463C5F6964003C3330323343443030313535303368425835427270325548413957483667666A6C50...**\" }", "code": 10334, "codeName": "BSONObjectTooLarge", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1703095214, "i": 24}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "qN+qTLJyb8//ZnqQ32GLbl2C83A=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 7277445925541249101}}}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:198)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:413)
```

Answer (score 1):

The server is rejecting something because it is larger than 16MB.  I would guess that the problem arises due to something in the pipeline passed when the change stream was started, but that was not provided in the question so I can't be sure.

The resume token in that error message is either:

- the resume token you included in the request
  In this case, use the resume token you already have to resume from the same place
- the resume token that marks the new position *after* the document that caused the error
  In this case, you haven't received document which would have corresponded with the resume token, so to have a logically continuous change stream, you should resume with the same token used in the request, i.e. the one you already have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but 16 mb error is handled by a script. The issue in the script occurs when it tries to read resume token. On the kafka side I can see the complete token but I think its truncated in mongo oplog itself. So does mongodb has some behaviour while copying from primary oplog to secondary it truncates data?

Comment: Mongod doesn't store resume tokens in the oplog.  Are you attempting to insert a document that contains the resume token and that is failing?

Comment: Yes Joe. I am taking value from document for kafka.

Comment: Can we see that code that generates this exception?